# Splitting Strings by Comma

Tags: macros, xparse, strings, xstring

I need to split a string by commas, and I haven't found an easy way to do it in `xstring` or `xparse` (although I may be missing something obvious). So if I say:

```
\def\pleaseHelp{"I, am, confused"}
```

What is the simplest way to extract:

```
{"I", "am", "confused"}
```

from `\pleaseHelp` and store it as a variable? I feel like this should be simple.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does it have to produce these additional quotes? TeX does not need them to mark it as string.

Comment: No, it doesn't need the quotes. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`listofitems` is a powerful list parsing package.  Your example is the simplest of its capability:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\pleaseHelp{I, am, confused}
\readlist*\mylist{\pleaseHelp}% star option removes surrounding whitespace
Individual items:\\
``\mylist[1]'' and\\
``\mylist[2]'' and\\
``\mylist[3]''

Loop over list:
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{\ifnum\xcnt=1\else\ and \fi``\x''}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, you can change the the parsing separator with the following prior to the `\readlist`:

```
\setsepchar{;}
```

You can parse based on several separators simultaneously with an or (`||`) separated specification of separators:

```
\setsepchar{,||.||;||:}
\readlist*\Z{To be, or not to be; that is the question.}
```

will yield a list containing `\Z[1]` as `To be`, `\Z[2]` as `or not to be`, `\Z[3]` as `that is the question`.

You can do nested parsing with a slash (`/`) separated list of separators, for example:

```
\setsepchar{*/,}
\readlist*\Z{this is, a test* of multi-level, parsing}
```

Then, `\Z[1,1]` contains `this is`, `\Z[1,2]` contains `a test`, `\Z[2,1]` contains `of multi-level`, and `\Z[2,2]` contains `parsing`.

When I use the word "contains", I mean "expands to the actual tokens, via two expansions" so that, in the above example, `\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\Z[2,2]}` will yield `parsing`.

Answer (score 4):

As you did not post a MWE here's a simple way to access such a comma separated list's items (have a look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf for further information):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \giveme } { m m }
{
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Which can be used as:

```
\giveme{I, am, confused}{1} % would return I which is item 1
```

If you really would like to store the variable have a look at the `l3clist` module described in the document I linked above.