# How to Capitalize a Glossary Entry Define by Another Glossary Entry?

Tags: beamer, glossaries, capitalization, glossaries-extra

I have glossary entries fields (as `name`, `text`, `symbol` fields) define by another glossary entry like below (the `compressor_motor` entry is define with the `compressor` entry):

```
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \glsname{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}
```

I would be glad to have (letter to Santa Claus ;):

- The `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\Glssymbol` and `\GLSsymbol` commands work with the `compressor_motor` entry (for the moment is not working, see MWE below);
- The `\Gls` command able to capitalize the first letter of **EACH** word, not just the first word (same behaviour as proposed by [karlkoeller answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134509/262081) with the possibility of putting a '~' character before each word - to prevent the 'lettered' word from being capitalized - as pointed out by Nicholas Hamilton in comment to the [karlkoeller answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134509/262081));
- Compatibility with Beamer **AND** article document class;

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={1}}   
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
    name={Compressor},
    text={compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    description={Air Compressor},
    symbol={cp},
    parent=subsytem
}
\newglossaryentry{ejector}
{
    name={Ejector},
    text={ejector},
    sort={Ejector},
    description={Air Ejector},
    symbol={ej},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \glsname{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_ejector}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor}~and \glsname{ejector}},
    sort={compressor and ejector},
    text={\gls{compressor}~and \gls{ejector}},
    description={Air \glsname{compressor} and \glsname{ejector}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}\glssymbol{ejector}},
    parent=subsytem
}


\begin{document}

    \gls{compressor};
    \gls{compressor_motor};
    \gls{compressor_ejector};
    
    \bigskip
    
    % This is not working: 
    %\verb!\Gls{compressor_motor}: !\Gls{compressor_motor};
    
    %\verb!\GLS{compressor_motor}: !\GLS{compressor_motor};
    
    %\verb!\Gls{compressor_ejector}: !\Gls{compressor_ejector};
    
    %\verb!\GLS{compressor_ejector}: !\GLS{compressor_ejector};
    
    %\verb!\Glssymbol{compressor_motor}: !\Glssymbol{compressor_motor};
    
    %\verb!\GLSsymbol{compressor_motor}: !\GLSsymbol{compressor_motor};


    \printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

So, I would like this kind of results:

[image]

---

**Why I define gls entries with another gls entries**?

Because I have a lot of entries (tens) depending to another entries and I don't want to change a lot of things if I just decide to change the word *compressor* by *compresseur* (in french for exemple). So, I had the idea to define all the entries using the word *compressor* by using the `\gls{compressor}` command...

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is here in order to not let this question without an almost "working" answer, if someone (by the greatest of chance) comes across this solution and wishes (strangely) to use it.
> **So, if someone comes with a more "LaTeX based" and robust solution (without using external tools) it would be great!**

## Two "bypass-solutions".

With both methods, the idea is the same: create a new `glossary_entriesPostTreated.txt` file used to define glossary entries but with all `\gls` like commands already "expanded".

This new file can be used instead of the original one (`glossary_entries.tex`) and the entries will capitalized without problem.

- The first method needs `make4ht` and a tool for `html` to text conversion (as `html2text`).
- The second method write directly to a text file (without an external tool) but use "low level" macros for writing the "output" of some `\gls` like commands to the file (thanks to [Marijn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634362/262081)).

### Prerequisite:

- All glossary entries definitions must be stored into a text file (`.tex`, `.bib`, etc.).

  - A newline **MUST** be present after each `\newglossaryentry` with no comments "`%`". So this is **Ok**:

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

But **NOT** this (a character is inserted just after `{subsystem}` and just before the first `{`):

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}% A comment here
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

or also **NOT** this (no newline inserted just after `{subsystem}` and just before the first `{`):

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}{% No newline here just after {subsystem}
{%
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

- Needs 3 packages: `listofitems` (to extract the entry fields, thanks to [Steven B. Segletes answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429895/262081)), `tikz` (to have a nice for loop), `catchfile` (to extract the content of the text file containing the entries definitions, thanks to [egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377141/262081)).
- The first method needs `make4ht` and a tool for `html` to text conversion (as `html2text`).

### 1. First Method (with `make4ht` and `html2text`)

MWE.tex (see explanations below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}% To make a nice for loop
\usepackage{catchfile}% To read the glossary entries file
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}
\input{glossary_entries.tex}

% For a good print of underscore
\catcode`_=12

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{glossary_entries.tex}% 
{\CatchFileEdef{\glsEntriesListString}{glossary_entries.tex}{\endlinechar=13}}%
\glsEntriesListString % This call is needed to a good behaviour of \readlist
\noindent
\ignoreemptyitems % Ingnore empty items from le list
\setsepchar{\newglossaryentry|| /,}% Define separator for nested list with e.g. first list separator "\newglossaryentry" or " " (space) and second list separator "," (comma)
\readlist\myglsentrylist{\glsEntriesListString}% Extract the list from glossary entriesc
\setsepchar{,}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\myglsentrylistlen}{%Loop under the glossary entry list
  \ifodd\i% If odd, print the list element
    \itemtomacro\myglsentrylist[\i]\myglsentrylisttowrite   
    \textbackslash{}newglossaryentry\{\myglsentrylisttowrite\}\{\%\newline
  \else % If even, make another list with the fields after removing curly braces "{}" surronding the fields
    \itemtomacro\myglsentrylist[\i]\myfieldslisttemp    \expandafter\def\expandafter\myfieldslisttemp\myfieldslisttemp % Removing curly braces "{}"
    \setsepchar{,}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
    \readlist*\myfieldslist{\myfieldslisttemp}% Ignore extreme spaces
    \foreach \j in {1,2,...,\myfieldslistlen}{%Loop under the glossary entry list
    \itemtomacro\myfieldslist[\j]\myfieldskeylisttemp
    \setsepchar{=}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
    \readlist\myfieldskeylist{\myfieldskeylisttemp}%
    \itemtomacro\myfieldskeylist[1]\myfieldskeylistONEtowrite
    \indent\myfieldskeylist[1]=\{%First item = field key name     
    \itemtomacro\myfieldskeylist[2]\myfieldskeylistTWOtowrite   
    \ifnum \j=\myfieldslistlen % Last field with NO comma at the end
        \myfieldskeylist[2]\}\newline\}\%\newline
    \else
        \myfieldskeylist[2]\},\newline
    \fi
    }%
  \fi
}%
\end{document}
```

Contents of `glossary_entries.tex` file:

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={Compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    text={compressor},
    description={Compressor},
    symbol={Cp},
    parent={subsystem}
}
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \gls{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent={compressor}
}
\newglossaryentry{ejector}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={Ejector},
    text={Ejector},
    description={Air Ejector},
    symbol={ej},
    parent={subsystem}
}
```

Build with:

```
$ make4ht -l MWE.tex
$ html2text -style pretty MWE.html > glossary_entries_PostTreated.txt
```

#### Explanations:

- The goal of the code is to print all the fields of all glossary entries using a similar method as the one used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633833/262081), called hereafter as the "`\printallglossaryfields` answer".
- Basically the code split the glossary entries fields with the `\readlist` command of the `listofitems` by considering them as a comma separated list (see [`\printallglossaryfields` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633833/262081) for more details).
- In order to print the curly braces around the fields (after the `=` symbol), the `\readlist` command is used to split the field key name (e.g. `sort`) from the field label (e.g. `compressor`) using `=` symbol as list separator (this feature was not present in the orignal code in the [`\printallglossaryfields` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633833/262081)).
- Underscore is defined with `\catcode'_=12` in order to be printed easily (need LuaLaTeX compilation with make4ht, see [michal.h21 answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634339/262081)).

#### Limitations and possible improvements (same as the [`\printallglossaryfields` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633833/262081)):

- Not robust with the need of newline after each `\newglossaryentry` with no comments "`%`" (because the code detects the space after each key in order to separate the key from the fields listed after the key).
- The use of packages `tikz` and `catchfile` could probably be avoided.
- Need an external tool for `html` to text conversion (e.g. `html2text`)

#### Bonus :

- Same as the [`\printallglossaryfields` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633833/262081).
- Works with new custom fields created by the user.

### 2. Second Method (with only LaTeX)

MWE (see explanations below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}% To make a nice for loop
\usepackage{catchfile}% To read the glossary entries file
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}
\newcommand{\entriesfilename}{glossary_entries}
\input{\entriesfilename.tex}

% For a good print of curly braces, percent and underscore
% Curly braces
\begingroup
\catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12
\gdef\wbgroup<{>
\gdef\wegroup<}>
\endgroup    
% Percent
\def\percentchar#1{}
\edef\percentchar{\expandafter\percentchar\string\%}
% Underscore
\catcode`_=12

% Redefinition of some \gls like commands by their respective "low level" macro in order to use them with \write command
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\gls}[1]{\csname glo@#1@text\endcsname}
\renewcommand{\glsname}[1]{\csname glo@#1@name\endcsname}
\renewcommand{\glsdesc}[1]{\csname glo@#1@desc\endcsname}
\renewcommand{\glstext}[1]{\csname glo@#1@text\endcsname}
\renewcommand{\glssymbol}[1]{\csname glo@#1@symbol\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newwrite\myoutputfile
\immediate\openout\myoutputfile=\entriesfilename_PostTreated.txt

\begin{document}
\noindent
% Read the text (.tex or .bib...) file containing the glossary entries definition
\IfFileExists{\entriesfilename.tex}%
{\CatchFileEdef{\glsEntriesListString}{\entriesfilename.tex}{\endlinechar=13}}%
\glsEntriesListString% This call is needed to a good behaviour of \readlist
\ignoreemptyitems% Ingnore empty items from le list
\setsepchar{\newglossaryentry|| /,}% Define separator for nested list with e.g. first list separator "\newglossaryentry" or " " (space) and second list separator "," (comma)
\readlist\myglsentrylist{\glsEntriesListString}% Extract the list from glossary entriesc
\setsepchar{,}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\myglsentrylistlen}{%Loop under the glossary entry list
  \ifodd\i% If odd, print the list element
    \itemtomacro\myglsentrylist[\i]\myglsentrylisttowrite   
    \textbackslash{}newglossaryentry\{\myglsentrylisttowrite\}\{\%\newline
    \immediate\write\myoutputfile{\unexpanded{\newglossaryentry}\myglsentrylisttowrite\wbgroup\percentchar}%
  \else% If even, make another list with the fields after removing curly braces "{}" surronding the fields
    \itemtomacro\myglsentrylist[\i]\myfieldslisttemp    \expandafter\def\expandafter\myfieldslisttemp\myfieldslisttemp % Removing curly braces "{}"
    \setsepchar{,}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
    \readlist*\myfieldslist{\myfieldslisttemp}% Ignore extreme spaces
    \foreach \j in {1,2,...,\myfieldslistlen}{%Loop under the glossary entry list
    \itemtomacro\myfieldslist[\j]\myfieldskeylisttemp
    \setsepchar{=}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
    \readlist\myfieldskeylist{\myfieldskeylisttemp}%
    \itemtomacro\myfieldskeylist[1]\myfieldskeylistONEtowrite
    \indent\myfieldskeylist[1]=\{%First item = field key name     
    \itemtomacro\myfieldskeylist[2]\myfieldskeylistTWOtowrite   
    \ifnum \j=\myfieldslistlen% Last field with NO comma at the end
        \myfieldskeylist[2]\}\newline\}\%\newline
        \immediate\write\myoutputfile{\myfieldskeylistONEtowrite=\myfieldskeylistTWOtowrite}%
        \immediate\write\myoutputfile{\wegroup\percentchar}% closing }
    \else
        \myfieldskeylist[2]\},\newline
        \immediate\write\myoutputfile{\myfieldskeylistONEtowrite=\myfieldskeylistTWOtowrite,}%
    \fi
    }%
  \fi
}
\immediate\closeout\myoutputfile
\end{document}
```

#### Explanations:

- Basically the same code goal as **Method 1** but here the entries are also printed directly into a text file (`glossary_entries_PostTreated.txt`).
- Some `\gls` like commands are redefine by their respective "low level" macros in order to use them with `\write` command (for good expand to the text file) (thanks to [Marijn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634362/262081).
- Curly braces are redefined in order to be printed to a file (see [egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47453/262081)).
- Percent character is redefined  in order to be printed to a file (see [Joseph Wright answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223089/262081))..

#### Limitations and possible improvements :

- Same as **Method 1**.
- Use non documented and non suported "low level" macros as `\glo@..@name` (the code may break on any update as pointed out by David Carlisle in comment of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634559/262081)).
- Only few `\gls` like commands usable here (`\gls=\glstext` `\glsname` `\glssymbol`).
- Doesn't Work with new custom fields created by the user.

#### Bonus:

- No external tool needed as `make4ht` or `html2text`.

### Result of both method (`glossary_entriesPostTreated.txt` file content):

[image]