# How to well convert underscore with catcode=12 with make4ht?

Tags: catcodes, make4ht, underscore

I have the following 'MWE.tex' file where I defined underscore with `\catcode'_=12`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`_=12
   
\begin{document}
Text containing underscore between parenthesis (_)
\end{document}
```

When I tried to convert this 'MWE.tex' file into html using Make4ht with the following command:

`make4ht MWE.tex`

I obtain this results in HTML (the underscore is not well converted):

```
Text containing underscore between parenthesis (˙)
```

My web navigator displays this:
[image]

**I there a way to obtain a good conversion of the underscore in this case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is typesetted diferently by `pdflatex` and by `lualatex`. `pdflatex` shows: `Text containing underscore between parenthesis (˙)`, and `lualatex` shows: `Text containing underscore between parenthesis (_)`. You get similar result with `make4ht` depending on the engine you chose for the conversion. When you use `lualatex`, it will display underscore:

```
make4ht -l MWE.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Alternatively, as you use an older system, you can try this configuration file for TeX4ht:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\catcode`_=13
\def_{\textunderscore}
\EndPreamble
```

It makes underscore active and defines it to produce `\textunderscore` command. I hope that this should work even on TeX Live 2019.

Compile using:

```
make4ht -c config.cfg MWE.tex
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer. Unfortunately, I obtain the same bad result with `-l`... My setup could be wrong. I have the v0.3d version of make4ht and working on Linux Unbuntu 20.04 LTS (stricly speacking on a Windows Subsystem Linux).

Comment: @SylvainRigal ah, I think that this can be the problem, your system is quite old. I can try to make a workaround that would work for you, but the preferred solution is to update your distribution.

Comment: Please don't spend time for this. I will update my distribution. What exactly is too old? Make4ht ?

Comment: @SylvainRigal I think the whole TeX distribution is too old. LaTeX itself was updated substantially in the last year, then TeX4ht and make4ht too.

Comment: @michal.21 Is it the Latex3 update? My install it's a fresh install (yesterday) with `apt install texlive-full` and `apt update` before. When I do `tex --version` I get `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) kpathsea version 6.3.1` I will try to upgrade something anyway.

Comment: @SylvainRigal yes, among others. Current TeX Live is 2021, and there will be TeX Live 2022 soon. The package on your system hasn't been updated for two years. But I will post a workaround that should work even on the older system.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot. Could you explain the meaning of the `config.cfg` file? Especially why `\catcodeˋ_=13` and not ` ` `=12`?