# How to list All Fields of All Glossary Entries?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

Is there a way to list all the fields of a glossary entry? If yes, is it also possible to do that for all defined entries automatically?

For exemple, something like a "`\printallglossaryfields`" command which list all entries and all fields of each entry (see MWE and expected results below) like a glossary print but printing all entries fields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={1}} 

\newglossaryentry{ejector}
{
    name={Ejector},
    text={ejector},
    sort={Ejector},
    description={Air Ejector},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={Compressor Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={compressor motor},
    description={Motor of the compressor},
    symbol={cpm},
    parent=subsytem
}


\begin{document}

    
    \verb!\printallglossaryfields: !

\end{document}
```

Here an exemple of the expected results by using the "`\printallglossaryfields`" command (I don't care about the exact text formating of the list because I will use this for txt conversion after, see "Why I want that?" section below...):

[image]

---

**Why I want that?**

Because I usually define glossary entries fields (as `name`, `text`, `symbol` fields) by another glossary entry like below (the `compressor_motor` entry is define with the `compressor` entry):

```
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \glsname{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}
```

And I would like to be able to convert all the glossary entries to a CSV file for sharing then with people who don't use LaTeX... For the moment I add the idea to first obtain the text given by `\glsname{compressor_motor}` (i.e. "Compressor Motor") and not the real content of the `name` field (i.e. "`\glsname{compressor} Motor`"). Then convert it into a text file (with Pandoc or htlatex for exemple) and after make a postprocessing (with bash probably) in order to obtain a CSV...

---

**To summarize**

Is it possible to have something like a "`\printallglossaryfields`" command which:

- List all entries (it is very important for me to print the key value of the entries as it apears in the `\newglossaryentry{...}` definition, like `compressor_motor`, with the underscore) and all fields of each entry (like a glossary print but printing all entries fields);
- Is flexible if there is not the same fields in all entries;
- Is able to deal with new entry field created by the user;

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is here in order to not let this question without an almost "working" answer, if someone (by the greatest of chance) comes across this solution and wishes (strangely) to use it.
> **If someone come with a cleaner/better solution it would be great!**

Here a solution (not really elegant and robust) for printing all entries fields (some explanation and discussion below the MWE):

**Prerequisite:**

- All glossary entries definitions must be stored into a text file (`.tex`, `.bib`, etc.).

  - A newline **MUST** be present after each `\newglossaryentry` with no comments "`%`". So this is **Ok**:

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

But **NOT** this (a character is inserted just after `{subsystem}` and just before the first `{`):

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}% A comment here
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

or also **NOT** this (no newline inserted just after `{subsystem}` and just before the first `{`):

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}{% No newline here just after {subsystem}
{%
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
```

- Needs 3 packages: `listofitems` (to extract the entry fields, thanks to [Steven B. Segletes answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429895/262081)), `tikz` (to have a nice for loop), `catchfile` (to extract the content of the text file containing the entries definitions, thanks to [egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377141/262081))

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}% To make a nice for loop
\usepackage{catchfile}% To read the glossary entries file
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries
\input{glossary_entries} % Need to be placed after the begin document for a good behaviour of \readlist command

\catcode`_=12% For a good print of underscore without using verbatim

\newcommand{\printallglossaryfields}[3]{{%
% #1 = name of the text file containing all the glossary entries definitions
% #2 = \endlinechar used by \CatchFileEdef for readinf the text file
% #3 = separator list in order to extract entries key, e.g. separator "\newglossaryentry|| " for set separator "\newglossaryentry" or " " (space) 
% Read the text (.tex or .bib...) file containing the glossary entries definition
\IfFileExists{#1}
{\CatchFileEdef{\glsEntriesListString}{#1}{#2}}
\glsEntriesListString% This call is needed to a good behaviour of \readlist
\ignoreemptyitems% Ingnore empty items from le list
\setsepchar{#3/,}% Define separator for nested list with first list separator "\newglossaryentry" or " " (space) and second list separator "," (comma)
\readlist\myglsentrylist{\glsEntriesListString}% Extract the list from glossary entries
\setsepchar{,}% Define separator for the list inside a glossary entry (in order to extract fields)
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\myglsentrylistlen}{%Loop under the glossary entry list
  \ifodd\i% If odd, print the list element
    \myglsentrylist[\i]\newline
  \else% If even, make another list with the fields after removing curly braces "{}" surronding the fields
    \itemtomacro\myglsentrylist[\i]\myfieldslisttemp
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\myfieldslisttemp\myfieldslisttemp% Removing curly braces "{}"
    \readlist\myfieldslist{\myfieldslisttemp}
    {%
    \foreachitem\x\in\myfieldslist[]{\ifnum\xcnt=1 \else\ \fi \indent\x\newline}% Print all list item (i.e. gls entry fields)
    }%
  \fi
}}}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\noindent
\printallglossaryfields{glossary_entries.tex}{\endlinechar=13}{\newglossaryentry|| }

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Contents of the `glossary_entries.tex` file:

```
\newglossaryentry{subsystem}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
name={Subssytems},description={},sort={1}}
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={Compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    text={compressor},
    description={Compressor},
    symbol={Cp},
    parent=subsystem
}
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \gls{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}
\newglossaryentry{ejector}
{% A new line is needed after each \newglossaryentry key !!!
    name={Ejector},
    text={Ejector},
    description={Air Ejector},
    symbol={ej},
    parent=subsystem
}
```

**`\printallglossaryfields` command explanations:**

1. Store the content of the file containing the entries definition (`glossary_entries.tex` = argument `#1`) in the `\glsEntriesListString` command (carrefull with the end line character to give in argument `#2`).
2. Split the entries between "entries key" and "entries fields" with the list separator given in argument `#3` (in e.g. the separators passed are "`\newglossaryentry||` " which means use "`\newglossaryentry`" **OR** (`||`) " " (space) as list separator) and put the results into a list: `\myglsentrylist`. **This is why a newline is necessary** in order to separate the "entries key" and "entries fields" (see "Prerequisite" section above) beause this newline is interpreted as a space by `\readlist` command.
3. Extract the fields (contained only in the even elements `\i` of the `\myglsentrylist[\i]`, the odd elements contains only the entry key alone as for e.g. `compressor_motor`) by removing the curly brace grouping them and make a list `\myfieldslist` by using the comma "`,`" list separator and directly print them with the `\foreachitem` macro given by the `listofitems` packages.

**Limitations and possible improvements:**

- Not robust with the need of newline afet each `\newglossaryentry` with no comments "`%`" (because the code detects the space after each key in order to separate the key from the fields listed after the key).
- The use of packages `tikz` and `catchfile` could probably be avoided.

**Bonus:**

- Works with glossary entry fields (as `name`, `text`, `symbol` fields) defined by another glossary entry like in the MWE (the `compressor_motor` entry is define with the `compressor` entry).
- Works with new custom fields created by the user.

**Results:**

[image]