# Parsing a Flat SGF String (with the Package listofitems)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, parsing, listofitems

I'm trying to parse an [SGF](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html) string with the package [`listofitems`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems?lang=en). SGFs are trees in text form, but right now, I'm working on only single-branched SGFs, for simplicity.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{
  % From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429895/64441).
  \setsepchar{;}
  \defpair{[]}
  
  \readlist\Z{#1}

  \begin{itemize}
    \foreach \i in {\Z}{
      % TODO: if key is either `B` or `W`:
      \item Color: {\i}[0] and Coords: {\i}[1]
    }
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
  \def\sgfA{;B[ab];W[cd]}
  \def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs])}

  \parseSgf{\sgfA}
  \parseSgf{\sgfB}
\end{document}
```

`sgfA` isn't proper SGF, just a simple example. I would like it to print an unordered list like this:

- Color: `B` and Coords: `ab`
- Color: `W` and Coords: `cd`

But I haven't been able to figure out how to use `\setsepchar` and `\defpair` to separate things properly, or how to use them in a `\foreach`.

`sgfB` is a proper SGF string. And there's the additional problem of ignoring keys that are not `B` or `W`. If anyone knows how to do it with `listofitems`, that would be a plus.

Comment: You really should not use `\foreach` for this. It is especially created for Ti*k*Z/PGF and does several things such as scoping and expanding that you will find annoying when used in another context. Why not stick to the functions provided by the `listofitems` package?

Comment: SGF seems to have a quite complicated syntax. So, I am unsure whether this can be simply parsed using some loops. But maybe, it can. You probably know that there exists a tool `sgf2dg` written in Perl that seems to allow to translate SGF to diagrams also in TeX format.

Comment: Oh. I actually didn't know about `sgf2dg`. Does it generate TeX code or EPS pictures? I only knew about the ancient `psgo` and `igo` packages, and that's why I'm trying to create a new package, because those are too old, and difficult to work with (also, I'm trying to learn more about TeX). In the past, I used to generate EPS diagrams through GoWrite2.

Comment: I don't know anything about `sgf2dg`. I just stumbled upon it when looking for more infomration about the SGF syntax.

Comment: The SGF editor [Sabaki](http://sabaki.yichuanshen.de/) is open source. And its SGF parser is [here](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/sgf) (I also have my own sort of working version [here](https://github.com/psygo/sgf-parser)). Maybe that could be useful. But I think, for this question, just splitting around `;` and `key[value]` should be enough.

Comment: Maybe then it would be enough to first split at `;` and then at `[` (and at `]` or just delete `]`). Are you bound to the `listofitems` package?

Comment: No, I'm not bound to `listofitems`. It just seemed very handy.

Comment: For `\sgfB`, what should the output look like?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes For `\sgfB`, these are the moves: `;B[as];W[bs];B[cs]`, the beginning is game metadata. So the output should be a this formatted as a list: `Color: B and Coords: as`, `Color: W and Coords: bs`, and `Color: B and Coords: cs`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes please do create a tag for your awesome `listofitems` package if you're able to. This way I can tag it here.

Comment: I have to depart for a couple of hours, but will have a further look.  One question: how am I to know, via parsing, that `;GM[1]...` is not part of a color/coords specification?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Because its key is `GM`, not `B` or `W`. All the fields are of the shape `key[value]`. Moves are represented by the keys `B` (Black) and `W` (White). There are plenty other "official" keys in the [SGF specification](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html) (the grammar actually doesn't disallow any key actually), but those are the two most important ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I undestand that you are primarily interested in the parts of the string which have the syntax `B[xy]` or `W[xy]` (where `x` and `y` are some single letters). The below code therefore ignores everything else.

This should probably not be considered the final version, but maybe something like this can do. I used expl sequences in this case as most of the things are related to splitting strings (note that a "missing item" error may pop up, if the string does not contain any suitable syntax):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne } % You might need to add this if the version of your TeX installation is not the most recent one 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nne }
\NewDocumentCommand{\parseSgf}{ m }{
  \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % remove ( and ) from string
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ( }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ) }
  % store the contents of #1 in a sequence with ; as delimiter
  \seq_set_split:Nne \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { \l_tmpa_tl }
  \begin{itemize}
    % loop over all items in sequence
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
      % split string at [ and store result in another sequence
      \seq_set_split:Nne \l_tmpb_seq { [ } { ##1 }
      \bool_if:nT { 
        % test if first part of sequence is B or W
        \str_if_eq_p:ee { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } } { B } ||
        \str_if_eq_p:ee { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } } { W } 
      } {
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } }
        % remove ] from string
        \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { ] }
        \item Color: ~ \l_tmpa_tl {} ~ and ~ Coords: ~ \l_tmpb_tl
      } 
   }
  \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \def\sgfA{;B[ab];W[cd]}
  \def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs])}

  \parseSgf{\sgfA}
  \parseSgf{\sgfB}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, on LaTeX Worksho on VS Code, I'm getting `Undefined control sequence. \parseSgf code #1->\tl_set:Ne` for this piece of code. @JasperHabicht, do you know what that is?

Comment: Maybe the installation is not new enough. Add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }` right after `\ExplSyntaxOn`. This should solve the issue.

Comment: True, that does solve the issue. My `tex -v` output says: `TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023)` (I think I installed it on my M2 Mac 2023 last October). Is that outdated already?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I am not sure. But it does not really matter, yours is surely new enough. Expl3 is updated quite often, as far as I know. Altough being stable, some code is added every now and then. Maybe this part was added very recently.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your answer to my drawing of moves code. More specifically, instead of `itemize` stuff, I would also replace `Color: ~ \l_tmpa_tl {} ~ and ~ Coords: ~ \l_tmpb_tl` with something like `\drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{\l_tmpb_tl}`. But I'm getting `Argument of \use_i:nn has an extra }`. Do you know why?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Try `\exp_args:Nee \drawStoneFromSgfCoords {black} {\l_tmpb_tl}` which first expands the arguments before executing the function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `listofitems` approach.  However, it will not test for improper syntax in the SGF string, such as `;B[ab[;W]cd]`, which will respond in the same way as the test case `\sgfA`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,tikz}
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}
\ignoreemptyitems
\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{;/[||]}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%
  \begin{itemize}
    \foreachitem \i \in \Z[]{%
      \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt,1]\tmp
      % TODO: if key is either `B` or `W`:
      \expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\tmp\endFirstof B
        \item Color: \tmp and Coords: \Z[\icnt,2]
      \else\expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\tmp\endFirstof W
        \item Color: \tmp and Coords: \Z[\icnt,2]
      \fi\fi
    }%
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
  \def\sgfA{;B[ab];W[cd]}
  \def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs])}
  \parseSgf{\sgfA}\bigskip
  \parseSgf{\sgfB}
\end{document}
```

[image]