# Problems expanding a variable inside a `\foreachitem` using the package `listofitems` and a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, parsing, listofitems

Following [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441), who's also one of the creators of the package [`listofitems`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems?lang=en), I'm now trying to use what that package was able to parse from a single-branch [SGF](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html) string inside a macro.

This is what I would like to be able to achieve, but I think I'm having expansion problems, because I'm getting a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error:

```tex
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}
\ignoreemptyitems
\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{
  \setsepchar{;/[||]}
  \readlist*\Z{#1}

  % This loop basically splits on `;`, which is a node/move delimiter in SGF
  \foreachitem \i \in \Z[]{
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 1]\stoneColor
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 2]\sgfCoords

    % These if's test the `key[value]` SGF format for the keys `B` and `W`, which denote Black and White moves, respecitvely
    % Other keys typically refer to metadata, or other secondary info.
    \if\stoneColor B
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{\sgfCoords} % if I hardcode the arguments, it works.
      % \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{Z[\icnt, 2]} % I've also tried stuff like this directly...
    \fi
    \if\stoneColor AB
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{\sgfCoords}
    \fi
    \if\stoneColor W
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{\sgfCoords}
    \fi
    \if\stoneColor AW
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{\sgfCoords}
    \fi
  }
}
```

Ideally, if anyone is able to find a solution to this, I would like it to find both Black or White moves (`B` and `W`) and edited (added) stones (`AB` and `AW`), so the if's would look like this:

```tex
\if\stoneColor { B \OR AB }
...
\if\stoneColor { W \OR AW }
```

But, of course, I can save this for another question, if it gets to be too much.

---

Here's a complete example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\usepackage{listofitems}

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}
\ignoreemptyitems
\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{
  \setsepchar{;/[||]}
  \readlist*\Z{#1}

  \foreachitem \i \in \Z[]{
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 1]\color
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 2]\sgfCoords

    \expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\stoneColor\endFirstof B
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    \else\expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\stoneColor\endFirstof W
      \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    \fi\fi
  }
}

\def\sgfA{;B[ab];W[cd]} % not truly valid SGF, just one simple example
\def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs])}
\def\sgfC{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs];PL[W]AB[dq]AW[eq])}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}

    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    % \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{black}{ab}
    % \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{white}{cd}
    
    \parseSgf{\sgfA}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are applying `\expandafter` (once) to `\color` which will not produce anything useful, and also using `\if` which comapres character code of character tokens.  What do you intent to test here? It;s hard to guess from the code shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added some extra comments to the first code block. Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Comment: as I think I mentioned before, using `\color` as a local variable will break any use of latex color commands in that scope, some but not all tikz color may work but it seems unnecessarily risky

Comment: Oh, yes. True, I forgot about that, sorry. I wasn't actually using `\color` in my code, it kinda got mixed up when pasting here. Just fixed it.

Comment: athough as it is, since you know it is B or W you can simplify `\expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\color\endFirstof B` to `\if\color B`

Comment: Another nice catch, thank you, @DavidCarlisle. I've updated and simplified the first and second code blocks, hopefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Don't use `\color`, since it overwrites an existing macro...I changed it to `\Color`.
2. The value of `\Color` will be `B` or `W`, which is not an actual color.  Therefore, I introduce `\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}` and `\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}` to convert `\Color` into an actual color.
3. The parentheses in the SGF definitions are also causing a problem.  They were not being parsed, but instead interpreted as SGF commands (but missing the associated `[]` datum).  Therefore, I hardwired the parsing to digest them away.  This approach solves the immediate issue, but may not be suitable depending on where you want to take this problem in the future.
4. The values of `\Color` and `\sgfCoords` needed to be expanded, prior to feeding them to your macro `\drawStoneFromSgfCoords`.  I accomplished this by expanding them into `\tmp` and then expanding `\tmp` into the macro invocation.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#2} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#2} - 1}
%
  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * 10cm / 18, \y * 10cm / 18)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\usepackage{listofitems}

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}
\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}
\ignoreemptyitems
\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{;||(||)/[||]}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%
%
  \foreachitem \i \in \Z[]{%
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 1]\Color
    \itemtomacro\Z[\icnt, 2]\sgfCoords
    \edef\tmp{{\csname thecolorof\Color\endcsname}{\sgfCoords}}%
%
    \expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\Color\endFirstof B
      \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
    \else\expandafter\if\expandafter\Firstof\Color\endFirstof W
      \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
    \fi\fi
  }%
}

\def\sgfA{;B[ab];W[cd]}
\def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs])}
\def\sgfC{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05];B[as];W[bs];B[cs];PL[W]AB[dq]AW[eq])}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{10 / 18}
    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
    \parseSgf{\sgfC}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you then disagree with @DavidCarlisle that these `if`s can become `\if\Color`? His simplification seems to be working with your code (I can create an edit on your answer, but this is also on my first code block).

Comment: Also, on that note, if I add two more `if`s for `AB` and `AW`, I don't think they get recognized because it only checks the `A`, the first letter of them. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Hmm... Just realized this probably won't work for parsing `AB` or `AW` because they are inside the same node (not separated by `;`).

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro my comment about `\if` was predicated on "you know it is `B` or `W`". If  it can be `AB` then you shouldn't be using `\if` at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is where I introduced `\Firstof`, to expandibly return the first token of an arbitrary-length input string.  That input string can be anything between semicolons that doesn't fit the `B`/`W` profile, such as `GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-02-05]`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ah well as i said my comment was predicated on it only being B or W but if AB acts like B and AW acts like W taking the first letter doesn't actually do the right thing either. (by the way that command is predefined in latex as `\@car....\@nil` and `\@cdr....\@nil` for the remainder, in honour of the lisp tradition, or honor even as it comes from Leslie.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, with each reincarnation of his question, the approach that previously was sufficient no longer is.  My latest approach to his more recent question is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709176/how-to-parse-a-keyvalue-string-with-the-package-listofitems/709324#709324.  I had to increase more depth nesting to my parser.